# How to get replies of replies in node-imap?

Tags: javascript, node.js, imap

I am trying to get the email thread based on in-reply-to Id with help of below code.

```
Imap.connect(config).then(function (connection) {
        return connection.openBox('INBOX').then(function () {
            var searchCriteria = [['HEADER', 'IN-REPLY-TO', messageId]];
            // var searchCriteria = [['OR HEADER "Message-ID" "' + messageId + '" HEADER "References" "' + messageId + '"']]
            var fetchOptions = {
                bodies: ['HEADER', 'TEXT', ''],
            };
            return connection.search(searchCriteria, fetchOptions).then(async function (messages) {
                let promises = messages.map(item => {
                    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        var all = _.find(item.parts, { "which": "" })
                        var id = item.attributes.uid;
                        var idHeader = "Imap-Id: " + id + "\r\n";
                        simpleParser(idHeader + all.body, (err, mail) => {
                            resolve(mail);
                        });
                    });
                });
```

It's working but it is getting replies for the current mail. I want to get replies of replies for the entire thread.

Comment: Add more details on yr code and environment

Comment: updated my question kindly check.

Comment: `var searchCriteria = [['OR', 'HEADER', 'IN-REPLY-TO', messageId, 'HEADER', 'REFERENCES', messageId]];` is close to what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried that, It is giving me the error, "Error: OR must have exactly two arguments".

Comment: I have tried this also, `var searchCriteria = [['OR', ['HEADER', 'IN-REPLY-TO', messageId], ['HEADER', 'REFERENCES', messageId]]];` .I am able to get the replies but not repies of replies.